# What do you call a certificate from a college or university that shows you have been admitted?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-order

What do you call a certificate that a college / university gives you as a sign of an agreement with your entrance to that specific academic institute? I need the most common fixed-term.

> - Letter of admission
> - Letter of admittance
> - Admission letter
> - Admittance letter

Comment: I would call it an acceptance letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After applying to a school, one will receive

> a letter of admission

if successful.

> admission letter

can be ambiguous since it can also be said to be part of an

> application for admission
>   admission application